# nullreference exception

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Using Linq to sql and server explorer, I mapped to a loginvalidation stored proc. So I write the following code:

```
ClientReportingDataContext db = new ClientReportingDataContext();
var data = db.ADMIN_LoginValidation(login, password);
```

It throws up an exception on the following line:

```
public ClientReportingDataContext() : 
        base(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FeedsConnectionString"].ConnectionString, mappingSource)
```

Exception thrown:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm calling this function from a unit test class. I cann feedsconnectionstring in web.config.

I put the web.config in the unit tests folder, and also under debug and debug/bin. Not sure what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance for any advise.

Comment: Seems to me like a bug like this should be easy to track down with a debugger. Put a breakpoint on line throwing the exception and find out which property is returning null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a unit test,

```
ConnectionStrings["FeedsConnectionString"].ConnectionString
```

won't be reading from your `web.config` file; it will be reading from the application configuration file for the test runner. Therefore, unless you've put `FeedsConnectionString` in the application configuration file for your test runner,

```
ConnectionStrings["FeedsConnectionString"]
```

is `null` and so

```
ConnectionStrings["FeedsConnectionString"].ConnectionString
```

is going to throw a `NullReferenceException`.

This is why testing and application configuration files don't get along well.

You should consider the following:

```
public ClientReportingDataContext(string connectionString) :
    base(connectionString, mappingSource)
```

Then inject your connection string in your test.